# Create loop to download 10 year data from Oanda via quantmod package

Tags: r, loops, quantmod, forex

I am trying to download bulk Oanda forex data using `quantmod::getSymbols`. The help file states that you can download only 500 days worth of data per request whereas I get a warning about a cap of 5 years worth of data from `warnings()`. Nevertheless, I tried to create a loop to download data from 1997 until this date. This is my code:

```
library(xts)
library(quantmod)

date_from = c("1996-01-01", "2001-01-02", "2005-01-03", "2009-01-03", "2013-01-04")
date_to = c("2001-01-01", "2005-01-02", "2009-01-03", "2013-01-03", "2016-01-04")
for (i in 1:5) {
  getSymbols("EUR/AUD", src="oanda", from = dates_from[i], to = date_to[i])
  forex = for (i=1) EURAUD else NULL
  final_Dataset<- rbind(c(forex, EURAUD))
}
```

What changes should I implement?

---

**Edit 1**
I made it work but it is sloppily written. Any proposed changes would be much appreciated.

```
date_from = c("1996-01-01", "2001-01-02", "2005-01-03", "2009-01-03", "2013-01-04")
date_to = c("2001-01-01", "2005-01-02", "2009-01-03", "2013-01-03", "2016-01-04")
forex = vector(mode = 'list', length = 5)
for (i in 1:5) {
  getSymbols("EUR/AUD", src="oanda", from = dates_from[i], to = date_to[i])
  forex[[i]] = EURAUD
}
EUR_AUD = Reduce(rbind,forex)
```

Comment: The warning is incorrect. The limit has been 500 days of history [since 2009-01-09](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/commit/70e06d723eafb365c5830b79ab1298f7e103ebce)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by looping over a vector of dates that are 500 days apart. Notice that I wrapped the `getSymbols` call in `try` because the first 2 starting dates did not work. I'm not sure why.

```
require(quantmod)
Data <- do.call(rbind, lapply(dates, function(d) {
  sym <- "EUR/AUD"
  x <- try(getSymbols(sym, src="oanda", from=d, to=d+499, auto.assign=FALSE))
  if (inherits(x, "try-error"))
    return(NULL)
  else
    return(x)
}))
```